# Why did my incorrect if statement work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error, logical-operators

I recently came across the following syntax error:

```
if (button=="init" || "show_selected" || "show_all") {
```

Of course this should have been:

```
if (button=="init" || button=="show_selected" || button=="show_all") {
```

HOWEVER, the original statement seemed to be working perfectly in Chrome, FF and IE9!?!? I only chanced upon my mistake while adding a new option.

To clarify, "init", "show_selected" and "show_all" are string arguments used when calling the function; e.g.

```
onclick=myFunction("init");
```

I'm sure I remember trying this kind of shorthand early on when learning JS and finding out very quickly that it **didn't** work.

I've already corrected the code anyway, but it's annoying me that I can't see why it was working.

Can anyone shed light on this enigma?

Comment: Well, it didn't work "perfectly" because the logic is incorrect, but it's certainly not a syntax error.

Comment: || "show_selected" will always be true

Comment: `"show_all"` is coerced to boolean value `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will work, and **it will always work** because your condition will be **always `true`**:

```
if (button=="init" || "show_selected" || "show_all")
```

Will always give true because `"show_selected"` is a string and if you pass it as an if statement condition it will be always true, your code is evaluated like this:

```
if (button=="init" || true || true) // Will always be true
```

Because writing `if ("show_all")` is equivalent to `if ("show_all" !== null)` which is `true`.

For example, try this:

```js
if ("show_all"){ //returns true (the statement is true)
   alert(true); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now. I had put in the if statement, assuming that I would eventually add options that would not use that part of the function. As it turned out, all options, so far, do use that code, which is why I didn't notice a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are expressions that are true values.

```
if ("show_selected") { /* ... */ }
```

… would run the code in the block.

You are using strings on the RHS of each of your OR statements, so the RHS of each is true.

---

Given:

```
myFunction("init");
```

Then:

```
button=="init"
```

Is:

```
true
```

So:

```
button=="init" || "show_selected" 
true || "show_selected" 
true
```

If you were to pass in any other value

```
button=="init" || "show_selected" 
false || "show_selected" 
"show_selected"
```